# How to search and validate plain texts (where it starts with http AND ends with .aspx) to be a valid hyperlink in a page body content?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

My web page content is populated by a plain text that is retrieved from a CDATA format - plain text data.

```
This is the site http://checksite.apsx to get information.

For more information, visit http://moresites.com/FAQ/index.html or search the site.
```

Now, my goal is to convert this plain text to a valid hyperlinks. 
I've used a  javascript code that does the conversion - `/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[^ ]+)/g;`
, but sometimes if there are multiple words, it captures an invalid URL.

My question: Is there a way to strictly capture any string that starts with "http" AND ends with ".html" or "aspx" will be converted into a valid hyperlink?

it should look like this -

This is the site http://checksite.apsx to get information.

For more information, visit http://moresites.com/FAQ/index.html or search the site.

Comment: i didn't see any differences between the input and the expected output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: how any string starts with "http" AND ends with ".html" or "aspx" will be converted into a valid hyperlink?

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) discusses a universal regex for URL.

Comment: @user3218114 - I would venture a guess that OP meant "**could** be converted`

Comment: *sometimes if there are multiple words, it captures an invalid URL.* share some inputs.

Comment: @syntaxcode could you explain the edit?

Comment: I removed the {} from the 2nd output to show that it should display as hyperlink for each plain text with http:* url string. Is it possible to define the regex that ends with .html or .aspx and display as hyperlink using the same match from http:*...-.html or .aspx?

Comment: @user3218114 - yes all instance of string starts with http:.... ends with .html or .aspx...

Comment: @user3218114 - since this is from a CDATA content, not sure why sometimes extra lines are included in the hyperlink conversion...